# HTML tabindex problem

Tags: html, css

I am stuck with a tabindex problem here. As you can see in the HTML mock up, I have four buttons namely **"Add", "Subtract", "Save" and "Close"**. When user Hits the Tab key, the flow starts correctly from **Add-> Subtract-> Save-> Close**, but after Close if user hits the Tab key again, the focus goes to the **TD TAG with comment "Jumping Here"**. What I want it to do is to go to Add button instead. I tried giving all Buttons a tabindex of **1, 2, 3, 4** then I tried giving every button an index of **1** and rest of the places as **-1** but that didnt solve the problem either. How do I solve this issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/t3ch/aNxjy/

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to prevent the user from tabbing to the links and option buttons in this page. If you do that, how is someone without a mouse (generally someone with a disability) supposed to access them?

Comment: @ AaronSieb, This is just the part of req. Whatever buisness wants :)

Comment: sometimes the people who make the requests have no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: Sometimes even though it go against best practices for UI and you voice your opinion it gets overridden by the people who sign your check.

Comment: It may seem a valid requirement in an intranet app, where the web-app is trying to mimic desktop applications which traditionally don't have links and other things to be worried about. I have seen such applications where focus cycles this way among defined fields, entirely skipping links and anything else. (wasnt the most "accessible" application per se, but thats what requirements stated) have posted an answer. See if that suits, protest to client that it goes against web accessibility guidelines, and implement anyway :)

Comment: HI Ravindra, you are right, this is an Intranet App.

Comment: You are in luck, then. Intranet apps generally have limited browser support. If you need to support only one browser, the code will be very small. Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is not possible. Just because you have a form with tabindex values, it doesn't mean those are the only elements that will receive focus. Even browser components, like the address bar, will receive focus at some point. The browser will use the tabindex you specify, but after that tabbing will cycle through everything else.

Comment: @stevelove, Well I just posted the current flow. I know browser puts own tabindex too. Maybe I should rephrase the problem as, After close botton I want the focus to move on to the Add button.

Comment: The only way to do this is to give the Add button a tabindex that comes after the the Close button. For example, Close: `tabindex=3` and Add: `tabindex=4`. But this means your tabbing won't start on the Add button. You cannot make these elements tab in a circular order by skipping everything else.

Comment: Thanks steve. So even if we assign a tabindex of -1 to a field, it doesnt actually neglect it altogether. right?

Comment: From what I've read, some browsers will use `tabindex=-1` to ignore certain elements, so that they cannot be reached by tabbing. But it doesn't appear to work in most browsers, and this is because a tabindex of -1 is not valid in HTML. The value must be between 0 and 32767 [http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex]

Comment: Tabindex of -1 is an HTML5 feature. It says: "If the value is a negative integer 

    The user agent must allow the element to be focused, but should not allow the element to be reached using sequential focus navigation." (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

Comment: @Alohci - Thanks for pointing that out. Sounds like the functionality I described.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like this idea but a way you could achieve this is registering an `onblur` event for the Close Button, then set the focus to what ever control you wanted...

This does work....

```
function resetFocusIndex(){
   var obj = document.getElementsByName('addIt');
   if(obj[0])
      obj[0].focus();
}


<INPUT TYPE="button" tabindex = "1" VALUE="Close" NAME="closeIt" onblur="resetFocusIndex()">
```

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script>

   function resetFocusIndex(){
      var obj = document.getElementsByName('addIt');
      if(obj){
        obj[0].focus();
      }
   }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body> 
   <TABLE WIDTH=95%>
      <TR>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="button" tabindex = "1" id="test2" VALUE="Add" NAME="addIt"></TD>
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="button" tabindex = "1" VALUE="Subtract" NAME="minusIt"></TD>
        <TD> </TD>
      </TR>
   </TABLE>

   <DIV>
     <TABLE BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="1">
      <TD> </TD>
      <TD>First</TD>
      <TD>Second</TD>
      <TD>Third</TD>
      <TD>Fourth</TD>
      <TR>
    <!-- Jumping Here -->  <TD><INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="selected" tabindex = "-1" VALUE=""></TD>     
     <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" tabindex="-1" NAME="" VALUE="" disabled></TD>
     <TD ></TD>
     <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" tabindex="-1" NAME="" VALUE="" disabled> </TD>
     <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" tabindex="-1" NAME="" VALUE="" disabled> </TD>

       <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="" VALUE="">
       <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="" VALUE=""></TD>
   </TR>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>

<TABLE>
  <TR>
    <TD><A HREF="#" tabindex="-1">Click Here!</A></TD>
  </TR>
  <TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>
  <TR>
   <TD>
     <INPUT TYPE="button" tabindex = "1" VALUE="Save" NAME="saveIt">
     <INPUT TYPE="button" tabindex = "1" VALUE="Close" id="test" NAME="closeIt" onblur="resetFocusIndex()">
   </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi gmcalab, why did you use obj[0]? We arent getting the array right? there is just one button with that name?

Comment: @t3ch - Because getElementsByName is returning Elements not an Element.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this it's an awful idea.

Have focusable items (eg `input`) preceding the first and following the last button in tab order. Hide them (eg by positioning them off the side of the page with `position: absolute; left: -1000px;`). When they get a focus event, move focus to the button at the other end of the tab order.

Don't do this it's an awful idea. Really.

Answer (score 1):

First you need 'id's for the buttons, that's always good.

Then you need to set two handlers; one on the last to tab to first, and one on the first button to shif+tab to the last.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/aNxjy/11/.

I used jquery, but you can accomplish this with regular js as well. Just that you'll have to do cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Here's the code for pure JS, firefox only implementation.. Notice how it is very similar to the original one: http://jsfiddle.net/aNxjy/12/. you may wish to use the onkeydown or onkeyup events if the onkeypress is already used. but they return different things in the event object.

Comment: Ravindra, I cant use jQuery and Browser is IE7/8

Comment: After going through bobince's answer above, I now remember how we used to do it.. there used to be two elements.. one with tabindex 0 and another with tabindex 32767. both were kept off the screen by using something like top:-9999px and on the focus of these elements, we used to write the logic to move to the expected first or last element. This way, we'd never touch the keypress handlers of the actual elements themselves.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aNxjy/13/ .. something needs to be set to false in the event.. i don't remember if it's the return value or the cancelBubble, try it out.

Comment: btw, that there is working code... just might need something more for certain scenarios

Answer (score 1):

Further to gmcalab's answer instead of getElementsByName you could use getElementById

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test2');
if(obj){
    obj.focus();
}
```

or possibly:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test2');
if(obj){
    obj.select();
}
```